# How to change a cells content in UltraGrid

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm trying to change the value of a sibling cell(day) if the value in the amount cell is updated. The problem is that I'm not sure how to access the  day cell. Here is what I have so far.

```
 private void UltraGridEdit_AfterCellUpdate(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Cell.Column.PropertyDescriptor.DisplayName.Equals("Amount"))
            {
                UltraGridHsaContributionEdit.ActiveRow.Band.Columns["StartDate"].?

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
e.Cell.Row.Cells["StartDate"].Value = DateTime.Today; //or whatever your date is
```

Answer (score 2):

You could access the sibling cell via the Row property of the UltraGridCell:

```
private void UltraGridEdit_AfterCellUpdate(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Cell.Column.Key == "Amount_Column_Key")
  {
    e.Cell.Row.Cells["StartDate"].Value = CalculateStartDateValue();
  }
}

private DateTime CalculateStartDateValue()
{
  // calculate start date value here
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came to very similar to both of yours.

```
private void UltraGridEditAfterCellUpdate(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Cell.Column.PropertyDescriptor.DisplayName.Equals("Amount"))
                {
                    UltraGridEdit.ActiveRow.Cells["StartDate"].Value = null;
                }
            }
```